# Is it possible to use substring with OfType<string>?

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, substring, checklistbox

I'm in a school project and I was wondering how show in a multiline textBox - not a listBox, that was part of the question - how to show the first five letters of checked items of a checkedListBox. We can't show them directly, we have to create an array that will be saved in a User class by using the constructor. My first thought was to use *selectedIndexChanged* event of the checkListBox and use an incremented, *.Items* and *.substring* to put the substring selected into an array. Here is my first code:

```
private void checkedListBox_programmes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selection = checkedListBox_programmes.SelectedIndex;

        if (selection != -1)
        {
            if (indice < 5)
            {
                tabProgrammes[indice] = checkedListBox_programmes.Items[selection].ToString().Substring(0, 6);
                indice++;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tableau de données est rempli");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*tabProgrammes and indice are initialise in my partial class

That didn't worked because unchecking index would add a string in my array.
So, second code (I use a buton_click event):

```
// remplissage du tableau avec les éléments sélectionnées
tabProgrammes = checkedListBox_programmes.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();

// création du profile
Profil unProfil = new Profil(textBox_Prenom.Text, textBox_Nom.Text, textBox_Utilisateur.Text, dateTimePicker_Naissance.Value, tabProgrammes);

// affichage des donnees
textBox_Affichaqe.Text = unProfil.ToString();
```

That work super well because I can check and uncheck without problems. **SO**, my problem is that I need to put in my array only the substring(0,6) of my checked items.
An idea?

Comment: Do you mean this? `checkedListBox_programmes.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().Select(x => x.Length > 6 ? x.Substring(0, 6) : x).ToArray();`

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: Yes, Enigmativity, that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Substring()` on the result of `OfType<string>()`.

To do so, you need to use the [Linq `Select()` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) in your specific case.

Here is an example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dataSource = new object[]
    {
        42,
        "bonjour",
        "allo",
        1000,
        "salut"
    };

    var myStrings = dataSource
        .OfType<string>()
        // In this case, we use substring only if the length of the string is above 6.
        .Select(s => s.Length > 6 ? s.Substring(0, 6) : s)
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var item in myStrings)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
bonjou
allo
salut
```

Comment: Thanks, that work really well. Can you explain me the => and the ?

Comment: `=>` is used for [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) and the `? : ` is a [conditionnal operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) equivalent to an `if/else`.

Comment: The statement "Yes, you can use `Substring()` on the result of `OfType<string>()`" is not strictly correct. They are not directly unrelated. You use `OfType<string>()` to ensure you have an `IEnumerable<string>` on which you can use `Select<string>(x => ...)`. You can then use `Substring(...)` on the `x` in the `.Select`.